# Setup Office 365 Account with Thunderbird

Tags: 16.04, thunderbird, office365

I am having issues with setting up an IMAP connection inside Thunderbird with both of my Office 365 accounts.

Thunderbird's error dialog states that I have the wrong username and/or password - but I have checked, and each account is correct.

Am I missing something, or is there a work around produced for this?

Comment: https://uit.stanford.edu/service/office365/configure/thunderbird  seems pretty straightforward :P  To help us out: are their any logs that contain errors? If you do this with tbird started from command line does it throw any errors?

Comment: Probably you find something helpful [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1059850)